# Doubt about the Fourier transform of one formula.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

well, the formula is as follow:

[image]

but i am pretty sure that this answer - zero is not correct, so could anyone help me out of this problem?

Comment: $F[\dot{x}(t)] = j \omega X(\omega)$ so $F[\dot{x}(t)^2] = (j \omega X(\omega)) \ast (j \omega X(\omega))$

Comment: your answer is correct, and i can totally understand that, but i want to know the exact result of F[g(t)]. can you help me with that?

Comment: Can you use what I wrote for obtaining the correct formula for  $F[g(t)]$ ?

Comment: does that matter?  but i still cannot find my mistake.

Comment: i am sorry if that makes it not readable since i don't know about how to edit formula on the website, so i just upload the pictures.

Comment: Come on .. $(-\omega^2 X(\omega)) \ast X(\omega)+(j \omega X(\omega)) \ast (j \omega X(\omega))$

Comment: the second term F[x(t)x˙˙(t)]=X(ω))∗(jω)^2X(ω))  =-w^2X(ω),but there is a - before F[x(t)x˙˙(t)], so still 0

Comment: No. Do you understand what is $\ast$ the convolution  ?

Comment: oh, i know. my mistake is that i didn't consider jω as a variant instead a coefficient. you really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

After discussion with user1952009, i have realized my mistake that i considered jω as a coefficient rather than a variant.

$F[x(t)\ddot x(t)]=-\omega^2X(\omega)*X(\omega)$

$F[\dot x(t)^2]=j\omega X(\omega)*j\omega X(\omega)\neq-\omega^2X(\omega)*X(\omega)$

Comment: $\ne -\omega^2 X(\omega) \ast X(\omega)$

Comment: And click on 'edit' in the other questions for seeing how to type in latex

Comment: thanks again. i am in china, it seems that my network always break down when i upload pics..